# Getting error when trying to install pycrypto on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, pycrypto

I get the following error when trying to install pycrypto with pip install pycrypto. I've passed the last 8 hours trying to fix it. If anyone has a way to install pycrypto without going through pip that would be nice. Currently when I run my Python script i get the : Crypto: Module not found error.

I have Build Tools installed as such:
[image]

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycrypto
```

[image]

I read that pycryptodome replaces pycrypto but even after installing, I get Module not found: Crypto.

Any help is appreciated.

I tried pip install pycrypto and I expected it to install it but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the pycrypto website](https://www.pycrypto.org/) new projects should use the `cryptography` package ([ref](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/)).

If you're working on an existing project, I would suggest, if possible, running it in Docker, otherwise switching to Linux. That aside, I would check out [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as a replacement for pip.

Otherwise, it looks like the way to go is installing `pycryptodome` from [from source](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/installation#windows-from-sources). Not sure how you tried installing it, though, so apologies if you already tried that...if so, did it error out? If it did not, could you post output of `pip3 freeze` from shell and VSCode?

Comment: pip3 freeze
ez-setup==0.9
pycryptodome==3.16.0
pyreadline==2.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pywin32==303
requests==2.11.1

Comment: Is that from shell or VSCode? Want to rule out PATH problems.

Comment: That's from cmd

Comment: I read that I should use easy_install but when i run easy_install I get the following error: failed to create process.

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 freeze` from VSCode? Again, I would strongly recommend using Docker or Linux if you can.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to provide a bit more information, step by step. Where did you read about using `easy_install`? I do not see it in the `pycryptodome` documentation. How are you running your python script? Are you able to at least try Docker?